# Business's networking goes down when main DNS server goes down despite backups

Tags: domain-name-system, dhcp, windows-server-2003-r2

Our business has multiple DNS servers that are AD-integrated. Our main server is WS 2003r2 (soon to be retired) and has AD, DNS, and DHCP. I believe that it is our only DHCP server. The last time we had to restart this server, the entire company lost access to internet and internal resources until it came back online.

According to the DNS records, all of the active DNS servers are listed as Name Servers. However, in the DHCP options on the main server, option 6 (DNS servers) lists only itself as a DNS server. Does this option need to be set to include every DNS server to have them take over DNS requests if the main server is to go down? I would test this myself but I cannot do so during the normal work day and would hope someone here could give some insight first.

Are there any other settings that need to be checked or set before our network can successfully use redundant DNS servers? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this option need to be set to include every DNS server to have
> them take over DNS requests if the main server is to go down?

Yes. DHCP Clients will only use the DNS servers assigned to them from the DHCP scope. Likewise, all of your static ip assigned devices should be configured to use more than one DNS server.

> I would test this myself but I cannot do so during the normal work day
> and would hope someone here could give some insight first.

You can add the additional DNS servers to your DHCP scope without impacting the DHCP clients. The next time the DHCP clients renew their lease they'll get the additional DNS servers as well. Until then they'll continue to use the DNS server that was assigned when they got their lease.